# Transparent Squid Proxy – issue opening a page in Internet Explorer

Tags: cisco, proxy, squid

**I set up Cisco Wccp + Squid on Suse Linux Enterprise 11 SP3.**

Firefox opens our intranet portal pages with no problems.  I can see requests to squid. I see cache hits and access in squid log. I see GRE traffic from Cisco on a tunnel in linux (for some reason only incoming RX – I see changing counters on the interface). I see squid returns elements from it’s cache by watching logs and visually. On a slow channel pictures appear immediately even if I clear Firefox cache.

Considering about a firewall in linux, I temporary deleted all rules on it. 
I’m not sure whether I cleared all of them? Can traffic drop somewhere?

That’s what basically I’m doing in console, when my server boots up:

```
modprobe ip_gre
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote y.y.y.y local x.x.x.x dev eth0
ip addr add x.x.x.x/32 dev gre1
ip link set gre1 up
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/lo/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/gre1/rp_filter
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i gre1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:3127
/etc/init.d/squid start
```

Note:

- x.x.x.x - ip-address of linux proxy with squid
- y.y.y.y - ip-address of my cisco router

I’ve got issues with Internet Explorer. I use IE 11. Occasionally, sometimes (usually) I have to hit Refresh Page button several times (like 5 or 6 times) to make page load from a remote server on a slow channel. The page usually doesn’t load from first time. I downloaded fiddler – http debugger. It shows ERROR 504 most of time.

I didn’t try other sites. Basically I’ve got one remote portal, and people work mostly with it.

What else did I try :

**CISCO IOS**

```
debug ip wccp events 
debug ip wccp packets
```

**squid.conf**

```
debug_options 80,3
```

I saw now errors in logs.

Question: how can I repair an issue with IE. I can’t get rid of IE, so I have to deal with it.

Comment: you're saying about slow links and refresh page. What is the type of links ? Could it be MTU problem ? What happens if you point client browser directly to use proxy ?